# Using a DEM to elevation data to an existing point shapefile

Tags: point, layers, dem

I have a point layer called air_quality_locations which contain points with air quality and ozone readings across California. I also have a 30m DEM for California. How do I take the elevation data from the DEM and add it to the point layer? I would like to make a scatterplot with the relationship between elevation and air quality.

Comment: Have a look at QGIS expression function `raster_value()`: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#raster-value Use it with field calculator

Comment: extending on Babel's comment here is that raster_value being applied in QGIS with 
 DEM and a point shp file https://youtu.be/lDRdevZhM3o?si=OHTCZX9fxSWQhtxa&t=646

Comment: And for ArcGIS or ArcGIS Pro see the Add Surface Information tool in the 3D analyst toolbox.  FYI, this tool will require that the point data and the DEM share a coordinate reference system or it will return a 999999 error.

Comment: in R, you can use `extract(DEM, points)` from {terra} package. http://www.sapijaszko.net/glupotki/posts/dem_altitude/ for example. For scatter plot just use `plot(altitude, air_quality)` or any fancy `ggplot` option.